# WooCommerce update price of a single product when the quantity is changed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store which I need the product price to update if the quantity is changed. Example if you wish to buy 3 mugs for $50, then the price will change to $150 on the single product page automatically, and as you increase the quantity the price shown will increase by $50 each time.

Most of my store is variable products, so the price must update on variable products as well as simple products.

The below code is almost there, but still not right. It doesn't work very well on variable products and doesn't update the main product regular price.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;


    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    echo sprintf('<div id="cart_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Cart Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
                        cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        $('#cart_total_price .price').html( currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));

                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

WooCommerce Single Page Product already does that out of the box and you dont have to do anything else to make it work, now you are hooking into woocommerce_single_product_summary but you are not doing any extra functioanlity there so there is no need for it, you add your extras in the templates of woocommerce itself and leave the base foundation functionality to WooCommerce to handle.

Comment: To the Person who down voted the answer would you care explain why and make a useful feedback to educate us!

Comment: When you change the quantity before adding the product to cart, the price does not change. It only shows the price for buying x1 of that item.